# How to decrease high CPU usage while program writes to WPF textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, textbox

I develop small WPF app and I have the following code to write logs in textbox:

```
    public void RemoteInfo(string message)
    {
        textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
        {
            DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + message + Environment.NewLine + textBox.Text;
        }));
    }
```

I call this method from the following code:

```
     Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                statusBarWriter.RemoteInfo("Some text");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
```

While this code is running CPU usage increases at least to 30% (after 30% I stop the program to prevent freezing).

What's wrong with the code and how can I prevent high CPU usage?

**UPDATE** second code snippet is up to date

Comment: are you running it in an endless loop? are new tasks spawned faster than it takes to update the textbox content? time to update will grow because you append text and never remove some.

Comment: The code you have posted will not cause 30% CPU usage unless its being hammered, how are you calling it

Comment: Instead of an endless loop with a Sleep, better use a DispatcherTimer. Its Tick event is fired in the UI thread, so you don't need to call BeginInvoke.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong second code snippet and now I update it. I run the code in endless loop like dlatikay says.

Comment: You're writing from one thread to the UI thread which will cause a lot of context switches. Using 'BeginInvoke' isn't a good design choice, because it uses PostMessage insted of SendMessage under the hood. So it would be better when you use events to signal changes to your UI thread,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing writing way, CPU load decreases and now it is about 0-1%:

```
    textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
    textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    textBox.SelectedText = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + message + Environment.NewLine;
```